# Creating own Task returning methods in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a simple authentication handler to be used with an ASP.NET Core Web API using the instructions of an article. The following code is a part of this work.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthenticationOptions>
{
    //Constructors and fields

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //Validation of bearer token 
        //No awaitable method calls
    }
}
```

Although this `HandleAuthenticateAsync()` method is marked as `async`, it doesn't actually await anything inside the method body at all. So, my questions are,

1. Do I really need to use a method decorated with async for this? Would it affect the application if I omitted the async keyword?
2. Can I rearrange this method which returns a `Task<AuthenticateResult>` in the following way without violating the best practices described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

```
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return new Task<AuthenticateResult>(() =>
        {
            //Token validation
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need to use a method decorated with async for this? Would it affect the application if I omitted the async keyword?

I recommend that you do keep the `async` keyword, and use a `#` to silence the compiler warning. With task-returning methods, any exceptions should be caught and placed on the returned task, and `async` will do that for you so you don't have to write that code yourself.

> Can I rearrange this method which returns a Task in the following way

No. You should never use the `Task` constructor.

If you don't want to use `async`, then return results using `Task.FromResult` and return exceptions using `Task.FromException`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decorate that method with ***async*** at all. Only if you will have something to be *awaited* there.

Your second point - you can totally do that but it hinders readability.

You can just follow the tutorials, which say the following:
If something is wrong and Authentication cannot be done, return the following:

```
return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Cannot Auth"));
```

If everything is good, just return

```
return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
```

The *ticket* being the `AuthenticationTicket` for the principal authenticating.

More info here: [Authentication scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2)